# Core-data add new non optional attribute to model with light weight migration

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to add a new non optional field to current model and upon migration set the value to already existing field.

Models:

```
ModelV1 {
   timestamp
}

ModelV2 {
  timestamp, creationTime
}
```

Upon migration I want to set the `creationTime` to `timestamp` as it is a non optional field. I don't want to provide a default value as it will be constant.

What I did:

- Create new version of model.
- Created mapping file v1 -> v2
- In mapping file set creationTime -> source.timestamp

But when I run the app I get this error:

> Cannot migrate store in-place: Validation error missing attribute values on mandatory destination attribute

The `creationTime` should not be empty as I have already provided the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was mapping model was not found by the app, i checked the installed app bundle and indeed the mapping file was not present. It was happening because the core-data migration mapping file was present in `MyLibrary` module but in the final framework it was not present.

I used cocapods to build the MyLibrary.framework, which needs to be updated to include the mapping file. I added this and it worked.

```
s.resource_bundles        = {'myLib' => ['myLib/Database/*.xcmappingmodel']}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should work. Since it isn't, it's possible that the migration process can't find the mapping model.

That could happen if you edited one of the models after you created the mapping model. Migration finds mapping models using model hashes, and editing the model can change the hash. If the hashes don't match, the mapping model won't be used even if it's present.

If you did that, re-create the mapping model and try again. If not, try using the migration debug flag to find out what's wrong. You can do this by adding `-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 1` to the arguments in the app scheme. Make the scheme "run" section look like this:

[image: Xcode scheme editor showing arguments field with the migration debug flag]

Then try to run model migration. What you should see is something like this:

```
CoreData: annotation: Incompatible version schema for persistent store '[...file URL...]'.  store metadata = {
```

...lots of detail about the model...

```
} and current model versions = {
```

...detail about the current model...

```
}
CoreData: annotation: (migration)    will attempt automatic schema migration
CoreData: annotation: (migration) found compatible mapping model [...file URL..]
CoreData: annotation: (migration)    Automatic schema migration succeeded for store at '[...file URL...]'
```

If you see nothing at all, then Core Data couldn't find your mapping model. If you see something different than this, read the messages carefully for clues about the problem. If you can't find the problem, try changing the `1` to `2` for the debug flag setting and try again to get even more detail on what migration is doing.